# Add custom text box with dynamic text on every product page

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I want to add a couple of lines of dynamic text to my product description.

Like this text

What is the price of "product name" in Singapore?
The latest price of "product name" in Singapore is "product price" You can buy the "product name" at best price from our "store name" or visit "store address"

I don't want to visit every product page to add this.

And I want google to capture the question (attached picture)
https://ibb.co/3YJ8dmk
https://ibb.co/wS73jpr

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You should develop a simple module which uses one of the Prestashop product [display hooks](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/) to show your dynamic informations.

A good starting point in module development is [here](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/creation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of theses hook to add your product custom fields ([See the doc](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/concepts/hooks/list-of-hooks/))

- displayAdminProductsExtra
- displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnMiddle
- displayAdminProductsMainStepLeftColumnBottom
- displayAdminProductsMainStepRightColumnBottom
- displayAdminProductsQuantitiesStepBottom
- displayAdminProductsPriceStepBottom
- displayAdminProductsOptionsStepTop
- displayAdminProductsOptionsStepBottom
- displayAdminProductsSeoStepBottom

See module demo to add custom fields https://github.com/PululuK/democustomfields17